# How to center img while display:block doesn't work?

Tags: css, wordpress, center, centering

I was searching for answer to my problem but nothing helped. Everyone talks about display:block then margin: auto and to give width so  I did, but it didnt work. that's how it looks:

img.custom-logo {
display:block; height: auto; width:100%; margin: auto;}

I'm working in wordpress if it's gonna help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you give with:100% then there is nothing to center

Comment: i guess you are right but when i give eg. 1600px it isn't working either.